# jQuery CSS positioning information not updating on Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tad604/dpRca/2/

That works as desired on IE and Chrome,  when it comes to Firefox it doesn't work right.

The desired behavior is to have a div (with the word foo) created where ever you click on the div containing the image.

With firefox the top/left positioning information is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"top":(ui.offsetY)+"px"
```

`offsetX`/`offsetY` (and the `offsetParent` they are calculated relative to) are non-standard event properties not available in Firefox.

Use `clientX`/`clientY` ([standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents)) or `pageX`/`pageY` (typically more useful; populated by jQuery from clientX/Y where not natively available) instead.

Comment: Not sure why the jQuery library doesn't automatically figure out the offset for you... I imagine it's doable.